# Is it possible to send SMS to mobile numbers which are shorter than 10 digits?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms, transactional-messaging-api

We are triggering some SMS sends from Sales Cloud using Marketing Cloud transactional API. We got an error which complains that one contacts has "invalid subscriberKey".

I tried to add this contact manually in Marketing Cloud mobile connect but got an error saying that the number must be at least 10 digits long. The mobile number is valid and includes also country code but it still is only 9 digits. In the country to which are sending, mobile numbers are normally 12 digits long (including country code) but there is a group of people who have shorter numbers. This BU uses scandinavian shorcode.

Any advises what could be done to fix this?

Comment: Does this help? 
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317212&type=1

Comment: Hi @NagendraSingh, unfortuntely the content you provided is related to another topic. The issue is not in the short code / From Name but Marketing Cloud refuses to add contacts whose mobile numbers are shorter than 10 digits.

Comment: Does adding leading zeros invalidate the mobile number?